# How do I manipulate a potentiometer over a wireless connection?

Tags: arduino, wireless

Hi and thanks for looking!

### Background

I am building a RC [multicopter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicopter) using a [KK controller](http://www.kkmulticopter.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=12&Itemid=65).

The controller has three potmeters to control gain/sensitivity for *pitch*, *roll*, and *yaw* channels.

Since I wanted to seal the controller in a canopy, I have already removed the potmeters and in their place wired three *thumbwheel* potmeters to the outside of the canopy so that I can adjust the gain as necessary.

This works fine.

### Question

I already am using three channels on my transmitter (each mapped to a trim knob) to talk to a separate circuit on the aircraft. Is there a way that I can use these three channels to adjust the pitch, roll, and yaw gains wirelessly?  Would I use a transistor in place of a potmeter?

I can use Arduino & etch a small PCB to accomplish this if necessary, I am just not sure what components to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered that there are [digital potentiometers](http://au.element14.com/analog-devices/ad5204brz10/digital-pot-quad-10k-5204-soic24/dp/9604090?Ntt=960-4090) out there that can do the trick!

Comment: As a caution, many digital pots, especially the cheap ones, have limited resolution. i.e. a 10K pot might only have 256 possible resistance values. For that reason, it's important to get one that exactly matches the resistance of the real pot so you don't lose any resolution.

Comment: Let me get this straight; you are accepting a voltage, to feed in to a digital pot meter, to (assumably) in a voltage divider configuration create a voltage. Why not just output a voltage the controller accepts for ranges the pot gives you normally?

Comment: @KennyRobinson--Because. . .that would. . .be too easy??  Ha ha--thanks for the suggestion, but I have a fancy scheme by which I use an additional channel on the transmitter to "shift" the "voltage" put out by the pin to an entirely different set of values to control other gizmos, so the data that I send out of those pins is always changing and I need a non volatile way for the P,R,Y gains to be stored.  Haven't had coffee yet so hope this makes sense.

Comment: @KennyRobinson--Your comment does make me wonder, however, if the digital pots will themselves be volatile so that I have to re-trim everything after the aircraft has been powered off and then back on.